# Loading content in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, lazy-loading, large-data

I am trying to understand Lazy Loading. Assume I have a big file which I need to load inside a text area in JScrollPane. Because any user will not see whole file at any point of time, I am currently loading 70 line at a time to be visible. Then, using scroll events, I decide when to load the next content.  I check whether the user while scrolling reaches the end, when the scroll is 2 units away from the end, I read the next 70 records from the file. Something like this I am doing:

```
public class LazyLoad {

    private static JTextArea txt;
    private static JScrollPane jscp;
    private static final int MAX_COUNT = 70;
    private static JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();

    private static FileReader fr;
    private static BufferedReader br;

    private static void createWindow(String title) {

        mainWindow.setTitle(title);
        mainWindow.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        mainWindow.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        txt = new JTextArea();
        jscp = new JScrollPane(txt);

        mainWindow.add(jscp);

        try{
            fr = new FileReader("src//f.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        } catch (Exception e ) {

        }

        loadText();

        JScrollBar vs = jscp.getVerticalScrollBar();
        int max = vs.getMaximum();
        int ext = vs.getModel().getExtent();

        vs.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Scroll value : " + e.getValue());

                // scroll is 2 units away from the end
                if ( vs.getMaximum() -( vs.getModel.getExtent() + e.getValue() ) <= 2 ) {
                    System.out.println("Loading more Text in the textarea");
                      // read next 70 lines.
                     loadText();
                }
            }

        });

        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    // This function is used to read next 70 lines and append them in the textarea.
    private static void loadText() {

        try {

            String line = "" ;
            int count = MAX_COUNT;

            while(count>0) {

                line = br.readLine();

                if ( line == null )
                    break;

                txt.append(line);
                txt.append("\n");

                count--;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        createWindow("Test for lazy loading");
    }

}
```

The above code reads the next 70 lines whenever the scroll is 2 units away from the end. But it keeps all of the text appended in textarea in memory. Let's say if I have 2 GB file, I can detect end of the file and loads the next set of lines to be read. But how to achieve the similar task when scroll is done upwards?

I went through other links saying implement a Document model, who wants to load 2GB or huge file inside TextArea. Please see, I am only trying to understand lazy loading via this example. And this can be useful for applications which need their custom editors or viewers for huge files.

Comment: I don't think this is easily possible with a JTextArea because the scroll bar would just take the size of the text that is currently loaded. What you could try is to get the number of lines of the text file and append empty lines before and after the currently loaded text to match the size of the original text.

Comment: 1) How do you know your formula results in a value < 2. The calculation should be assigned to a variable and then test the variable. This way you can display the value to make sure it is reasonable. 2) The variables used in the calculation should be determined in the listener. It's possible the max or extent could change if the frame is resized for example. 3) I don't see where you remove the existing text, so I would definitely expect the max to change. 4) When you load the text is the listener firing as you load the text. Maybe you need to remove the listener while the text is added?

Comment: @camickr As per your points I made a small edit of updating the extent and max values inside listener which now seems to be showing expected behaviour. But how to lazily load the content when scroll is done in upwards direction. Currently, all content resides inside the textarea which will take too much of memory for large files.

Comment: @Grunzwanzling Will not memory consumption in that case be equal to file size? Large files may have huge number of lines.

Comment: No, you have the same length in lines but not in chars. The memory usage will be much less

Comment: @Grunzwanzling Okay, but then how will I be able to load lazily? Currently I made scroll's end as the criteria for loading more content. What will be the deciding factor in your approach?

Comment: You create two variables that determine the start end the end of the currently loaded excerpt. When the scroll bars come close to these values you load something new.

Comment: `when scroll is done in upwards direction` - well I would guess you need a second if condition. You already have one as you get close to the max. So now I guess you need one as you get close to the min. Maybe you need to keep a variable of the last position so you know whether the value is increasing or decreasing.